# How I can grant write permission to the file Preferences.sublime-settings and locate this file of Sublime Text 3 using Elementary OS Luna?

Tags: linux, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I cannot grant write permission to the file `Preferences.sublime-settings` in Sublime Text on Elementary OS Luna 3. If someone went through it, can you help me?
There is no way to go to the directory where it is because it simply is not in the way I get by clicking with the *right button of mouse > Copy File Path*.

I get this path:

```
/home/llarruda/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

In the directory Packages i just have the directories *User* and the *link of current directory* (.) and *level return link* (..).

I sailed across the directory tree for the Sublime Text 3, via bash, listing including hidden directories, nothing positive. I tried to grant permissions recursively to the for the whole Sublime Text 3 directory and even the innermost level that I can access and should contain the file `Preferences.sublime-settings`, I haven't success.

I did the install from the *.deb* package obtained on the official website.

PS: I want grant write permission, but I force give to the whole directory full permition - `sudo chmod -R 777 sublime-text-3`, that inside on *.config directory*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ST3, plugins/packages are run directly from the `.sublime-package` file. For most things, you don't actually need the contents of those files. For instance, you can create a `Preferences.sublime-settings` in the user folder, and it will be merged properly. That being said, ST3 does allow you to override files. To make things easier, you can use the plugin [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). I wrote it to assist with viewing default files. Again, you don't need to do this for your particular case though. In the menu, go to `Preferences -> Settings - User`. This will create a preferences file in the user directory. When merged, the values in the `User` directory will be used rather than those in `Default`.

Comment: Thanks by attention, I will look better about you explained me, and check your plugin. I already knowed about the definitions of settings in the directory User - although had not thought to change the location of my definitions -, but do you know how I can access the Preferences.sublime-settings and how it dosen't there in the path that Sublime shows me?

Comment: You can use the plugin to open the Default preferences. If you make some change and save it, it will create the file where you are expecting.

Comment: Nice plugin, @skuroda. I can access many setting files, Thanks by the little hand.